# IntelXDK : IOS Build Failed on admobpro plugin

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, plugins, intel-xdk

I m trying build IOS app through IntelXDK and i got this error when i try to run build option.

My CLI version is 5.1.1 & IOS version is 8. I have attached all the required certificates & provisioning profile.

Please help me

Thank You

```
duplicate symbol l017 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
duplicate symbol l018 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSITimeRecorder.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADRewardBasedVideoAd+Mediation.o)
duplicate symbol l008 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdAttributionView.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADPushTransitionView.o)
duplicate symbol l014 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADPinger.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdAppViewController.o)
duplicate symbol l016 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADNativeAdImage.o)
duplicate symbol l005 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMWebViewRenderedChecker.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewRenderedChecker.o)
duplicate symbol l006 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMWebViewRenderedChecker.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewRenderedChecker.o)
duplicate symbol l012 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSI.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSIReporter.o)
duplicate symbol l009 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADInterstitialPool.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdView+VideoAdditions.o)
duplicate symbol l010 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADInterstitialPool.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdView+VideoAdditions.o)
duplicate symbol l022 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMAdapterHTML.o)
duplicate symbol l023 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSIConfiguration.o)
duplicate symbol l016 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdNetworkJavaScriptAdViewDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol l017 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADBannerAdViewDelegate.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdNetworkJavaScriptAdViewDelegate.o)
duplicate symbol l002 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAdViewTouchGestureRecognizer.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADAbsoluteTime.o)
duplicate symbol l018 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADCSITimeRecorder.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDPicture.o)
duplicate symbol l021 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDResizeProperties.o)
duplicate symbol l022 in:
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADLocation.o)
    mytestapp Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADMRAIDResizeProperties.o)
ld: 28 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Ld build/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Release-iphoneos/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mytestapp\ Downloads normal armv7
    cd .../mytestapp/platforms/ios
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=8.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Developer/android-sdk-macosx/tools:/usr/local/ant/bin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch armv7 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.0.sdk -L.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/device -L.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/mytestapp\ Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-extension -F.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/device -Fmytestapp\ Downloads/Plugins/cordova-plugin-admobpro -filelist .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Release-iphoneos/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mytestapp\ Downloads.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=8.0 -framework AssetsLibrary .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -weak_framework Social -weak_framework MessageUI -lCordovaGenericAd -framework GoogleMobileAds -framework AdSupport -framework AudioToolbox -framework AVFoundation -framework CoreLocation -framework CoreTelephony -framework EventKit -framework EventKitUI -framework Foundation -framework QuartzCore -framework StoreKit -framework UIKit -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Release-iphoneos/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mytestapp\ Downloads_dependency_info.dat -o .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Release-iphoneos/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Objects-normal/armv7/mytestapp\ Downloads

** BUILD FAILED **


The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Release-iphoneos/mytestapp\ Downloads.build/Objects-normal/arm64/mytestapp\ Downloads normal arm64
(1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-project,mytestapp Downloads.xcodeproj,ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,-target,mytestapp Downloads,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphoneos,build,VALID_ARCHS=armv7 armv7s arm64,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/device,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=.../mytestapp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
Command finished with error code 2: .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build --release,--device
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: .../mytestapp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/Developer/cordova/5.1.1/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:134:23)
    at ChildProcess.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:753:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:5)
```

Comment: can u list out the plugins u have added?

Comment: Okay build is working now after removing cordova-plugin-admobpro plugin but i want to have cordova-plugin-admobpro plugin in my app. my app need to have admob ads. please help

Comment: any1.?? please help URGENT

Answer (score 0):

Only Cordova CLI v5.x and newer support loading Cordova-plugin-admobpro from npm.

Some tools or build services (PhoneGap Build, Intel XDK, Microsoft VS2005, etc.) are still using an old version of Cordova CLI and did not support it well yet. A bug report is created to PhoneGap build service, see: https://github.com/phonegap/build/issues/439

Currently, using the old plugin id com.google.cordova.admob is a workaround.