# Linker Command failed with exit code 1 Error in Xcode 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, xcode10

I got linker error when application running in Xcode 10.  But application successfully running in Xcode 9.

```
/Users/akirankumar/Documents/Projects/ProjectName/Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds(GADGestureIdUtil.o)
ld: 159 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
Showing All Messages
:-1: 159 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
Showing All Messages
:-1: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here app run fine in simulator,  strange to see error in device.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35458412/intelxdk-ios-build-failed-on-admobpro-plugin, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32159983/duplicate-symbols-for-architecture-arm64-xcode-error, and so on

Comment: @matt here app run in simulator but error in device